# SQL Server Data Without Duplicates items

Tags: sql-server

Is there any possible way/Query in SQL Server in which I can fetch column values except duplicates. Below is the Example

```
id | device_id | company_id  |  
1       1           4         
2       1           4      
3       2           4
4       3           4
```

From above table I only want data of columns whose device_id is not duplicate i.e  device_id =2 and 3 . I know about distict but by using distinct I get one value of duplicate also , but I only want result without duplicates .
Hope I am able to explain my problem .
TIA
  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. You can use `COUNT(*) OVER(..)`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY device_id) N
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  id,
        device_id,
        company_id
FROM CTE
WHERE N = 1;
```

You can use a join with a derived table:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM dbo.YourTable T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT device_id, COUNT(*) N
            FROM dbo.YourTable
            GROUP BY device_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) T2
    ON T1.device_id = T2.device_id
;
```